# I've lost everything on my iphone4, how do I put my library back? Syncing doesn't work

Tags: iphone, restore

First my phone said "No wi-fi" so I reset everything on the phone, the phone now has nothing on it & asked me to set it up again. I opted for 'restore from back-up' instead of 'new phone', now it is instructing me to connect into itunes but it syncs all the songs & stops & the phone still instructs me to connect to itunes - I'm going around in circles. I don't know how to get my phone back to how it was. can anyone help please. I don't have Ninety something dollars to call apple for help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting your phone to the mac / pc you're usually syncing it too? Because it would need the backup file which is created everytime you sync it.

If so, you should try this instructional guide. It has screenshots and should be easy to follow. If this does not work write what's happened.

http://ipod.about.com/od/iphonetroubleshooting/ss/restore-iphone.htm

Comment: Great, I followed this, took a while but everything is back just as it was, just had to set my screen pics again. However, I still have the original problem, which was that in my iphone Settings where I'm suppose to be able to turn my WiFi on or off, it is just grey & says 'No WiFi'?! Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: could you attach a screen shot to your question? (Go to the screen you are referring to, and press Home and Power button simultaneously for a second or so - the screen will blink). The screenshot will be in your photos folder and you could grab it while connected to iTunes.

Comment: A friend of mine had the same problem, but he poured cola over his iPhone... Did you have any kind of water-connected issues with your phone? ;-)
Keep in mind that taking the cold phone into a wet environment (taking a long shower) could cause this too.